# How GET/REQUEST all values from a field in a database (phpMyAdmin) using SQL and PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I am currently doing work with a database online. The is entries from different countries and I need to do a drop down list for these countries. Rather than typing the countries into the HTML is there any way of using GET/REQUEST or anything to get the data from the database to create a drop down?

Obviously, there are a few duplicate countries such as I think USA occurs 3 or 4 times but I would like that to appear on the list only once.

*Update:* coming to think of it GET/REQUEST can't be used so is there an alternative possibly using an SQL statement?

Comment: Have you took a look at [some SQL queries basics](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic structure of an HTML dropdown is:

```
<select>
   <option>Option1</option>
   <option>Option2</option>
   <option>Option3</option>
</select>
```

Knowing that, simple make a query from your database, and loop through the values. Assuming you already know how to do that.

```
<select>

<?php
while(<loop through each value in database>){
    echo "<option>{$data}</option>";       //Assuming $data has current iteration's value
}
?>

</select>
```

Comment: How would you prevent duplication of values?

Comment: You make sure you dont get duplicates when you query your database. If you are using SQL, maybe make use of DISTINCT() in your SELECT statement or GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

the equivalent sql statement for GET is SELECT.